# Fastest method to implement string lookup

Tags: string, lookup

I want to code a small project in C where I want to give the user an option to uniquely name any of 500 addresses. The name length can be up to 8 characters. What would be the best way in terms of speed for looking up an address by its assigned name?

Comment: a hash map perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [search lookup structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure) most fit for your use case.

If read operation is your priority, then choose hash table, but be aware that quality of your hash table is tightly coupled with your hash function quality.